How do I read data from an old Access .mdb file with Excel 64-bit
Have an old Access 97-version .mdb file
I read the data from VBA in Excel 32-bit with the connection string "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
Now Excel has been updated to 64-bil version and the connection to the database file is not working.
I have tried to change to "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" but the error "unable to open file created in previous versions" appears.
So is there any option to make this work?
Converting the .mdb file to a newer version is not an option.
Regards

I'm happy to be proven wrong, but I don't think that there is a solution to your problem. There is no 64-bit version of Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0, there is no way to load a 32 bit OLEDB driver in a 64-bit process, and Microsoft is not going to add support for ancient file formats to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. Sorry! (I mean, seriously, 1997 is more than 25 years ago. Many people developing software today weren't even born in 1997.)

As noted below, you can install the x64 bit version Access 2010 version of ACE data engine, and it would in theory allow you to open that mdb file with a x64 bits in process as you have. Note that you don't have to install the whole Access application, and you don't have to instlal the access runtime, but can install the ACE data engine.

You can open these if you install the Access 2010 database engine, which has 64-bits support and support for Access 97 files. The connection string you had should work, provided you have the Access 2010 database engine. As the Access 2010 database engine was the only version with both 64-bits support and support for Access 97 mdbs, any other version won't do.
Note that you cannot simultaneously install Office with Access included, and the Access Database Engine, so if you want to open these in Excel you need to install an Office version which doesn't include Access.
Also note that Access 97 files are out of support for over 10 years, and the Access 2010 database engine has also been out of support for many years. You'll need to track down an unofficial source, as these are no longer provided by Microsoft.
For more details on the compatibility of mdb versions and Access versions, see https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000462.shtml.

OK, thanks.
As I also would need a normal Access installed on the system, this, sadly, is not an option.
I wll have to figure out another solution.
